# Firestore efficiently inserting documents in subcollections

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm creating a firestore document that's not at the root level of an existing collection but somewhat deeper:

```
  const response = await addDoc(
    collection(
      firestore,
      'stats',    //collection
      'dayStats', //document
      'years',    //collection
      '2023',     //document
     'january',  //collection
    ),
      statData
  );
```

At the time of creating an event, the entire subcollection structure might not exist yet, but only a part of it.

This results in intermediary documents not being created. They are in italics and there's a warning for them saying "This document does not exist, it will not appear in queries or snapshots".

The issue with this is that I need to be able to query for all years in day stats. E.g. the code below returns empty array instead of [2022, 2023] due to those docs being the ones in italic.

```
  const response = await getDocs(collection(
    firestore,
    RootCollections.Stats,
   'dayStats',
    'years',
  ));
```

I need to be as efficient as possible. I don't consider a transaction acceptable here as I would triple the number of requests my app is making (GET to check whether 'dayStats' exists, GET to check whether '2023' exists, then write, and this is the best case scenario for each and every inserted doc).

The ideal solution would be for firestore to create intermediary docs under the hood. This way I would be charged as 3 reqs only first time, and as 1 req for every other doc that falls in an existing year-month bucket. However, I understand that this is not possible.

I would hope there's an efficient solution for this. Subcollections architecture tripling (or even more, depending on how deep the insert is) the number of reqs is a huge red flag that should be bolded in the docs and I didn't even see it anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The ideal solution would be for firestore to create intermediary docs under the hood.

That won't happen. When you write code to create a single document, no matter where it lives, only a single document will ever be created.  In most cases, it would be more surprising for extra documents to be created other than the one that was requested.  Missing parent documents is normal and expected in Firestore.

It's time to consider whether or not using subcollections like this even makes sense for your use case. If your code is trying to check if a collection "exists" (which they don't exactly, not like folders in a filesystem which must exist in order to accept files within them), then that's likely not the right way to organize and query your data. Checking the existence of a subcollection isn't the right way to use a subcollection.

It sounds like you actually just want to put all documents in a single collection, and put the year in a field of each document.  If you want to know if there are documents with a given year (meaning that year "exists" in your documents somewhere), then just [count the results of a query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/aggregation-queries) filtering the collection on that year value. From the documentation:

> The server calculates the count, and transmits only the result, a single integer, back to your app, saving on both billed document reads and bytes transferred, compared to executing the full query.

Comment: I'm never checking for existence of a collection, but of a document.  And I'm querying collections that might not be there. However, I get what you're saying and your answer probably still applies, meaning I cannot bypass this constraint in any reasonable way, correct? Also, this is great that counting feature arrived, been waiting for that one

Comment: also I don't see a reason not to expose an api to force create ancestor docs to those like me that might benefit off of having it.

Comment: If the only purpose of checking the existence of a document that serves no purpose other than the signal the existence of some other data, then it's really just the same thing in spirit.  If that's what you really want, you're free to do it, but it's not really good design for this type of database.

Comment: You are free to send your feature request to Firestore staff, but I honestly don't think this has any chance of being implemented.  It's just not the way Firestore was meant to be used. https://groups.google.com/g/google-cloud-firestore-discuss

Comment: These were some excellent answers, thanks